# Email everyone in a google group except myself

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, google-groups

We have a group of techs in our company. As the list grows it becomes harder and harder to remember who to add. We want a group of emails (e.g. techs@mycompany.org). Whenever one of us wants to send out an email we want to email everyone but not ourselves. How is this set up in GSuites?

Comment: Welcome. It looks that the question isn't complete. Do you have G Suite accounts?

Comment: Seems like I wrote out my question didn't finish it.

Comment: I didn't use Google Groups recently to send emails. It use to be that senders didn't get a message in their inbox. Are you getting a message in your inbox? Did you joined the group using a Google Account? Are you sending the message from the Google Groups UI? By the way, I think that here there are questions asking the opposite, how to make that the sender get a message in their inbox.

Comment: Comment thread makes it seem like we need more detail. If you don't want to get the email in your inbox, you can send your Groups message via Gmail. If the recipient is techs@mycompany.org, then you won't get the email in your inbox (it will be in your sent folder).